# Insert number of records based on field value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following script :-

```
SELECT
   quoteid,
   tariff_length,
   cost 
FROM
   tblquotesnew q 
   LEFT JOIN
      tbltariffsnew t 
      ON q.tariff_id = t.tariff
```

which may return something like:-

```
quoteid tariff_length cost
310     4             12
311     6             16
```

Is it possible to INSERT rows into a seperate table, where the number of rows inserted is based tariff_length?

So, using the above, the insertion table (tblcommnew) would look like

```
commid quoteid cost
1      310     12
2      310     12
3      310     12
4      310     12
5      311     16
6      311     16
7      311     16
8      311     16
9      311     16
10     311     16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (quoteid, tariff_length, cost) as
  2    (select 310, 4, 12 from dual union
  3     select 311, 6, 16 from dual
  4    )
  5  select rownum as commid, quoteid, cost
  6  from test,
  7       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                           connect by level <= tariff_length
  9                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

    COMMID    QUOTEID       COST
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        310         12
         2        310         12
         3        310         12
         4        310         12
         5        311         16
         6        311         16
         7        311         16
         8        311         16
         9        311         16
        10        311         16

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on @Littlefoot's approach is to use an XMLTable to generate the combinations:

```
with tblquotesnew (quoteid, tariff_length, cost) as (
            select 310, 4, 12 from dual
  union all select 311, 6, 16 from dual
)
select rownum as commid, quoteid, cost
from tblquotesnew
cross join xmltable ('1 to xs:integer($n)' passing tariff_length as "n");

    COMMID    QUOTEID       COST
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        310         12
         2        310         12
         3        310         12
         4        310         12
         5        311         16
         6        311         16
         7        311         16
         8        311         16
         9        311         16
        10        311         16
```

As an insert you then just do:

```
insert into tblcommnew (commid, quoteid, cost)
select rownum, quoteid, cost
from tblquotesnew
cross join xmltable ('1 to xs:integer($n)' passing tariff_length as "n");

10 rows inserted.
```